# networkx maximal_matching() does not return maximum matching

Tags: python, graph, networkx, matching, bipartite

I'm learning to use the *networkx* python module to do some matchings of a bipartite graph. There are two functions in the module that give the maximum cardinality matching of a graph:

1. `nx.maximal_matching()`
2. `nx.bipartite.maxmum_matching()`

Note that although with the name of `maximal_matching`, its doc does state that it "Find a maximal cardinality matching in the graph."

Since my graph is a bipartite one, I assume these 2 would give same results, at least both with the same number of edges. However my code seems to suggest that the `nx.maximal_matching()` gives the wrong answer: it is possible to have one more edge, as the `nx.bipartite.maxmum_matching()` suggests.

Below is my working code:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx import bipartite    

def plotGraph(graph,ax,title):    
    pos=[(ii[1],ii[0]) for ii in graph.nodes()]
    pos_dict=dict(zip(graph.nodes(),pos))
    nx.draw(graph,pos=pos_dict,ax=ax,with_labels=True)
    ax.set_title(title)
    return   

if __name__=='__main__':    
    #---------------Construct the graph---------------
    g=nx.Graph()
    edges=[
            [(1,0), (0,0)],
            [(1,0), (0,1)],
            [(1,0), (0,2)],
            [(1,1), (0,0)],
            [(1,2), (0,2)],
            [(1,2), (0,5)],
            [(1,3), (0,2)],
            [(1,3), (0,3)],
            [(1,4), (0,3)],
            [(1,5), (0,2)],
            [(1,5), (0,4)],
            [(1,5), (0,6)],
            [(1,6), (0,1)],
            [(1,6), (0,4)],
            [(1,6), (0,6)]
            ]

    for ii in edges:
        g.add_node(ii[0],bipartite=0)
        g.add_node(ii[1],bipartite=1)

    g.add_edges_from(edges)

    #---------------Use maximal_matching---------------
    match=nx.maximal_matching(g)    
    g_match=nx.Graph()
    for ii in match:
        g_match.add_edge(ii[0],ii[1])

    #----------Use bipartite.maximum_matching----------
    match2=bipartite.maximum_matching(g)    
    g_match2=nx.Graph()
    for kk,vv in match2.items():
        g_match2.add_edge(kk,vv)

    #-----------------------Plot-----------------------
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

    ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
    plotGraph(g,ax1,'Graph')

    ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
    plotGraph(g_match,ax2,'nx.maximal_matching()')

    ax3=fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
    plotGraph(g_match2,ax3,'bipartite.maximum_matching()')

    plt.show()
```

And here is the generated plot. As is shown subplot-2 has 6 edges while 3 has 7. Is this a bug in the networkx's implementation or I'm doing anything wrong here?

PS: my networkx is version 1.11

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`networkx.maximal_matching`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.maximal_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.matching.maximal_matching) algorithm does not give a **maximal cardinality** match in the manner you intend.  It implements a simple greedy algorithm whose result is maximal purely in the sense that no additional edge can be added to it.

Its counterpart, for the global maximum cardinality match you intend, is [`networkx.max_weight_matching`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching)

Comment: I got it. I didn't even look into `max_weight_matching` as my graph has no weights. Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: I understand the difference between the two now, but I wonder when can the **maximal matching** be useful? Does anyone have examples of problems when it would be good enough to find maximal matching, not necessarily the maximum matching?

Comment: If you have huge graph and need to find a quick solution, it simply is faster, at the expense of quality of course.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer to [this bug report](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1301), the matching returned is maximal, rather than a maximum matching. Which in their terminology (I don't know how common this is) means that is gives a local optimum rather than a global optimum.

So, for the matching returned by maximal_matching it is only guaranteed that it can not be made larger by adding an edge to that matching (while still being a matching). However, it is not guaranteed that there does not exist a matching that has more edges.

Answer (score 0):

In graph theory parlance, maximal matching and maximum matching are different (even in a bipartite graph). Maximal matching simply means you cannot add any more edges to it as pointed out by donkopotamus. Maximum matching means no matching has more edges than it. This is why the functions are thus named.

That said, there is no such thing as a maximal cardinality matching in graph theory. But unfortunately documentation uses the wording "maximal cardinality matching". This easily leads to people getting confused; or worse misunderstand the purpose of the algorithm.